# Tezos Development Toolchain

Tags: node, documentation

Are there similar libraries in Tezos ecosystem similar to the OpenZeppelin library and the Hardhat development environment in Ethereum?

Comment: I'm not sure what OpenZeppelin / Hardhat is. It seems like libraries of trusted (community-vetted) components that can be used to compose smart contracts. As far as I know, there is no such thing for tezos. The closest thing is probably Archetype: it is a high-level language for Tezos smart contract that also contains a library of formally verified components: https://archetype-lang.org/

Answer (score 1):

The closest to OpenZeppelin I've seen are the collection of contracts made by TQ Tezos here:
https://github.com/tqtezos

And for a Hardhat-type tool for deploying contracts (not sure what else Hardhat does...) you can use Taquito:
https://tezostaquito.io/docs/originate/